# Spark apply function to certain columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe with N columns and I have a hashmap where the keys are the columns names and values a tuple (string, boolean).

For each column that is on the hasmap and meets a certain condition -some comparison with the tuple - I have to apply a function to all the elements of that column.

In the end, I have to modify some columns of a dataframe that meet some condition depending on the column name.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do. can you be more specific and share example data, expected output and actual code?

Comment: @mtoto  How can I create a dataframe from an array of dataframe?

Comment: Scala, Java or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using foldLeft on your hashmap. Here's an example for Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val colMap = Map(
  "col1" -> ("a", true),
  "col2" -> ("a", true),
  "col3" -> ("a", false)
)

val df = Seq((1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

def verify(strValue: String, boolValue: Boolean): Boolean = {
  strValue == "a" && boolValue
}
def processColumn(c: Column): Column = c * 2

colMap.foldLeft(df) {
  case (curDF, (colName, (strValue, boolValue))) => 
    if(verify(strValue, boolValue)) curDF.withColumn(colName, processColumn(col(colName)))
    else curDF
}
```