# Scala - Dataframe - Select based on list of Columns AND apply function to some columns

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark dataframe to process some files, and my requirement is as follows

1. I need to select specific columns from dataframe and create another dataframe - this is simple
2. I need to apply some function to specific columns from data frame and create another dataframe - I am able to do it

```
//For 1
dataframe.select("COLUMN1") 
//more specifically I use the below
dataframe.select(listOfCol.map(col): _*)

//For 2
/dataframe.withColumn("newColumn", someUDF(col("COLUMN2")))
```

But I need both to be applied together in a elegant way, I came across this - [Spark apply function to certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001159/spark-apply-function-to-certain-columns)

Can I follow this **OR** is there any wat better, any suggestion or direction would be great help. thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

There is predefined map that will give which specific columns what functions (if needed) are applied, a sample one

```
example val colFunctionMap = Map(
  "COLUMN1" -> ("function1", true),
  "COLUMN2" -> ("function2", true),
  "COLUMN3" -> ("", false),
  "COLUMN4" -> ("", false),
...
)
```

so I need something like this - **below is just a sudo code**

```
dataframe.select(
     for each (listOfCol)
       if function has to be applied -> Apply and select column
       else -> just select column 
)
```

Please let me know if you need any other details...

Comment: How do you know which columns will have the function applied? Do you have an example of the input and output?

Comment: Yes I have a data structure like map that is going to tell me what method should be applied for specific column/s.. I have edited the question about that information

Comment: I used the same principle like -  Spark apply function to certain columns, I will post the answer here...